# iBeacons and CBService Broadcast simultaneously

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-location, ibeacon, core-bluetooth

Is it possible to simultaneously broadcast my iOS app as an iBeacon and at the same time publish a service?

My app currently advertises a service, which works perfectly fine. My client app (central) is able to find the peripheral, connect, obtain the service and read data from the characteristic. However, if I update my server app (peripheral) to start broadcasting as an iBeacon emitter in addition to the service, I am no longer able to find services that I setup to advertise on the client app (central).

The idea of this is that I want to be able to read information from the server (peripheral) app when in close proximity from the client (central).

Is this technically feasible?

I was thinking about turning off iBeacon transmission when a device comes into close proximity and then starting the service broadcast, but there is no API in Core Bluetooth that calls back to the emitter when a client device enters the region being advertised.

Is this doable? Is there a workaround that would achieve something along these lines? I would like to avoid any networking, as this should be an offline solution.

Answer (score 0):

Taz, For sure you can be an iBeacon and you can look for iBeacons. What I did and what I see other doing is combining iBeacons with other services, such as the CloudKit [which yes, means networking too] to add functionality to their basic functionality.

That said I can imagine an app in which your iBeacons switch to a different protocol when they see each other, the challenge; how-to negotiate a channel/UUIDs for a BLE peripheral/central pair.

I am still in the process of building, but have implemented something similar over the past months... in short you hardcode an initial channel to start your BLE conversation, your first and only exchange on said channel being to agree a new BLE one to use.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to look for other iBeacons. I want to broadcast as an iBeacon and at the same time broadcast a CBService. Is that even possible?